# Reseting time or world messes with joint_state_controller

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After time or world reset, `joint_state_controller` stops publishing `/joint_states` for a while and then it catches. This window can take quite a long time. I suppose, it is caused by publishing frequency mechanism, which cannot recover from time reset and just waits to get to the time of reset (source code [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/a075bc36ebf5b81a7dafe911907cc1b781dd0185/joint_state_controller/src/joint_state_controller.cpp#L82)).

Is this a standard behaviour? Can it be avoided otherwise then rewriting the controller itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27033/reseting-time-or-world-messes-with-joint_state_controller/) by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The ros controllers were not developed for Gazebo. So, for a real robot, this code is valid.

If this behavior is a problem for you, then you have two options:

- write a world plugin that initializes time upon reset, such that it's strictly increasing
- write a model plugin that reloads the controllers upon reset. You can use the controller manager services for that

  class Plugin : public ModelPlugin {
  virtual void Reset() override {
  ctrl_mngr_srv.call(...);
  }
  };

Otherwise, GazeboRosControlPlugin should address this directly.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on 2021-06-04**:
Thanks for the answer! Looking at the code, I believe that `JointStateController` will not be corrected by `GazeboRosControlPlugin` on time restart, since it holds its own last update time value. This was also my experience from experiments. Another thing was, that also other controllers misbehaved after time resetting (even with `GazeboRosControlPlugin`). However, on world reset they worked just fine.